# MySQL / EF 6.0 Core One-to-One relationship returns null

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-6, c#-6.0

I am using EF Core 6.0 with MySQL (Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql v6.0)
I am setting up my database via code first. Here are my 2 models (simplified):

```
public class Store : BaseEntity
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public virtual User? Owner { get; set; }
     public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
}
public class User : BaseEntity
{
     public string? Name { get; set; }
     public virtual Store? Store { get; set; }
}
```

For both, I have

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

as the primary key (from BaseEntity).

I also have Lazy Loading enabled here:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
}
```

and in the Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt => opt
    .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
    .ConfigureWarnings(warning => warning.Ignore(CoreEventId.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning))
    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
    .UseMySql(
        Globals.DB_CONNECTION_STRING, new MySqlServerVersion(Globals.MYSQL_SERVER_VERSION),
        o => o.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery)
            ));
```

Now, to the problem - I am trying to get a store from the database, using the following code:

```
Store? store = await dbContext.Stores
    .Include(x => x.Owner)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Owner.Id == ownerId && x.Id == storeId);
```

I am getting the store details, but the Owner object and OwnerId is null. I can see the data in the database (e.g. I see OwnerId is set up for this specific store), but in the code, it is null.

I read on SO that Pomelo has some issues with setting up navigation properties, so I set it manually in OnModelCreating as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Store)
    .WithOne(x => x.Owner)
    ;
```

But that didn't do the trick.

The same configuration works perfectly with MSSQL.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call HasForeignKey after WithOne and point to OwnerId.

Comment: I have tried that. It didn't work. Thanks